# Named patterns in Except

Tags: function-construction, bugs, pattern-matching, downvalues

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and fixed in 10.4.0**

<sup>Bug isn't present in version 5.2</sup>

---

I don't think I quite understand how `Except` works.

I want to define $f(a,b) = (a-b)\ln(a-b)$, with the special case $f(a,a)=0$.  Except, the function shouldn't evaluate if either $a$ or $b$ is zero.

I tried:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[Except[0, a_], Except[0, a_]] := 0;
f[Except[0, a_], Except[0, b_]] := (a - b) Log[a - b];
```

But for some reason `DownValues[f]` only reports one definition:

```
DownValues[f]
(* { HoldPattern[ f[Except[0, a_], Except[0, b_]]] :> (a - b) Log[a - b] } *)
```

This is bad because if the user inputs `f[x,x]`, I get Infinity::indet errors.

**Question** What did I do wrong, and how do I make definitions with `Except`?

Comment: I'm tempted to say this is a bug. In any way, this is not a case of one pattern having more priority than the other or so. If you change the order of the definitions you'll see the last one is always kept. It seems that Mathematica (incorrectly) sees both patterns as equivalent.

Comment: I agree that this is a bug. ``Internal`ComparePatterns`` returns "Equivalent" for the two cases which is clearly not correct.

Comment: @SimonWoods too bad this is a bug.  Add the 'bugs' tag?

Comment: Yes I think the bugs tag is justified. Please also report it to Wolfram Research.

Comment: Sent bug report to Wolfram

Comment: With *Mathematica* 5.2 I observe the expected behavior but with 8.0.4 I reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another way to get two definitions is to only use `Except` on the first argument for the case where the arguments are identical.

```
Clear[f]

f[Except[0, a_], a_] := 0

f[Except[0, a_], Except[0, b_]] := (a - b) Log[a - b]
```

Annoyingly it doesn't matter the order for the definitions it comes out like this:

```
DownValues@f
(* {HoldPattern[f[Except[0, a_], Except[0, b_]]] :> (a - b) Log[a - b], 
 HoldPattern[f[Except[0, a_], a_]] :> 0} *)
```

So in order to get the right behaviour you have to do

```
DownValues[f] = Reverse@DownValues@f
(* {HoldPattern[f[Except[0, a_], a_]] :> 0, 
 HoldPattern[f[Except[0, a_], Except[0, b_]]] :> (a - b) Log[a - b]} *)
```

Now

```
f[3, 1]
f[3,0]
f[2,2]
f[0,0]
```

gives

```
2 Log[2]
f[3,0]
0
f[0,0]
```

Comment: if you do `f[a_, Except[0, a_]] := 0` it takes care of the `DownValue` order issue.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that `f[Except[0, a_], Except[0, a_]]` isn't considered doubled argument while this

`f[a : Except[0], a : Except[0]]` is. So the former isn't considered special case and is overwritten by your next definition.

I can't explain properly but seems to be expected.

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_, a_] := 0  (*or f[a : Except[0], a : Except[0]] if f[0,0] should give f[0,0]*)
f[a : Except[0], b : Except[0]] := {a, b}



f[1, 2]
f[0, 1]
f[0, 0]
f[1, 1]
```

> ```
> {1,2}
> f[0,1]
> 0
> 0
> ```

Comment: Yes, that's what I need, thanks.  Can you explain what went wrong with what I did, too?

Comment: @QuantumDot I edited the answer, still without full explanation.

Comment: Another workaround is to use a trivial condition to stop the definition being overwritten, e.g. `f[Except[0, a_], Except[0, a_]] /; True := 0`