# Bug: With[] pattern-variable renaming misses symbols within `Except`

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, scoping, symbols

**Bug introduced in 10.1 and fixed in 11.1**

> Thank you for taking the time to send in this report. It does appear that pattern-variable renaming misses symbols within Except when using With. I will forward an incident report to our developers regarding this issue, and include the discussion in the stack exchange article.

---

```
With[{u = {f}},
 HoldPattern[G[f_, Except[f_]]] :> u
 ]
```

gives

> `HoldPattern[G[f$_, Except[f_]]] :> {f}`

I would expect

> `HoldPattern[G[f$_, Except[f$_]]] :> {f}`

Bug?

Comment: I agree that this is a bug, adding the tag.

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have (or will) report the problem?

Comment: I'd expect neither. I don't understand why is `f` touched at all. Curiously, if you try `With[{u = {f}}, HoldPattern[G[f_, Except[f_]]]]` you get `HoldPattern[G[f_, Except[f_]]]`.

Comment: maybe related: [101903](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/101903/5478)

Comment: @rcollyer That's because `:>` is a scoping construct and could potentially have `f` on the RHS as well (in addition to the LHS as a pattern name).  In that case the uniqueness (localization) of `f` must be guaranteed.  Mathematica is a bit overeager in doing this.

Comment: @Szabolcs it took some playing around to convince myself that is what is expected. It is interesting to compare these three: `With[{u = {q}}, Hold[SetDelayed[G[f_], f]]]`, `With[{u = {q}}, Hold[SetDelayed[G[f_], f + u]]]`, and `With[{u = {q}}, Hold[SetDelayed[G[Except[f_]], f]]]` for the variances in behavior.

Comment: @Szabolcs I filed a report.

Answer (score 12):

I agree that this is a bug. However, I want to point out that this usage of `Except` does not seem to be allowed in older versions.

In version 9.0:

[image]

We don't get the expected `True` answer.  An error message is issued.  The error message is also triggered by your example.

In version 10.0:

[image]

The error is *not* triggered by your example in version 10.0.2.  (It is triggered by other similar examples such as the `MatchQ` above.)

In version 10.3.1 everything works fine:

[image]

It seems that this usage of `Except` is new in 10.1, 10.2 or 10.3 and that the renaming rules were not yet updated to be compatible with it.  With this context, it seems like a bug.

The change is not mentioned on the documentation page of `Except`, which is annoying.

Comment: Narrowed down the window, it's between 10.0 and 10.2.

Comment: @rcollyer The `True` result is given in 10.1.0.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I could have figured that out, eventually. But, it would have required unpacking 10.1.0, etc., and it couldn't exceed the threshold of my laziness. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is when you provide a pattern as the first argument of `Except`.
Although, given as a second argument the pattern is preserved, the context now changes:

```
With[{u = {f}},
HoldPattern[G[f_, Except[_, f_]]] :> u
]

(* HoldPattern[G[f$_, Except[_, f$_]]] :> {f} *)
```

Pattern provided as either a first or a second in `Except` will yield different contexts e.g.

```
Cases[{1, 2, b, 3, 4, a, 5}, Except[_Integer]]
(* {b,a} *)

Cases[{1, 2, b, 3, 4, a, 5}, Except[# &, _Integer]]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} *)
```