# What changes were made to core functions during the 10.x series?

Tags: core-language, compatibility

I am looking for a list of changes to how core functions work (documented or undocumented), which happened during the 10.x series, along with the version in which the change happened.

Uses for this information:

- Ensuring package compatibility.
- Possible implementation of a [linter tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)).

Answer (score 9):

This is an incomplete list, please add more entries.  Please help in finding out the version where the change happened.

#### `Except` with named patterns

`Except` accepts named patterns: `MatchQ[f[x,y], f[z_, Except[z_]]]`

Mentions: [Bug: With[] pattern-variable renaming misses symbols within `Except`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/125248/bug-with-pattern-variable-renaming-misses-symbols-within-except/125293#125293)

Documented: No.

Since version: 10.1 or 10.2 (please update)

#### `Table` with integer repetition

`Table[expr, n]` replaced `Table[expr, {n}]` as the documented syntax.

Mentions: [Unexpected behaviour from Table[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124046/12)

Documented: Yes

Since version: 10.2 (per documentation)

#### Pattern with non-matching default value (`Optional`)

Pattern matching with default value succeeds even if the default value (`Optional`) doesn't match the pattern.  Example: `f[val_List : All] := "match"`.  `f[]` evaluates in later versions but not in 10.0.

Mentions: [Version inconsistency with optional arguments: what if the default value doesn't match the pattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108636/12)

Documented: No.

Since version: 10.1 or 10.2 (please update)

#### `AssociateTo` with association as 2nd argument

`AssociateTo` can take an association as its second argument.

Documented: The fact is mentioned in a documentation example.  The version when the change took placed is not documented.

Since version: between 10.1–10.3

#### `Nothing` removed from associations

In versions 10.2 and 10.3, `-> Nothing` is removed from associations, but not `:> Nothing`.

Since version 10.4, it isn't.

Documented: Yes. Version where change occurred is documented. *What* the change was is not mention in later version documentations, so it is necessary to manually compare doc pages.

#### Sequential `With`

Multi-definition form for `With` is allowed:

```
With[{a = 0}, {a = a + 1}, {a = a + 1}, a]
```

Mentions: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/121173/12

Since version: 10.2 or later

Documented: This form of `With` is not officially documented as of version 11.0

Comment: **I know that there are many more undocumented small changes, so please add to the list!**

Comment: Iterated `With[list1,list2,...,body]` I think is in that time range.

Comment: Operator forms, e.g. `Cases[pattern][list]`.

Comment: @Daniel Do you know which operator forms were added after 10.0 for functions that were already present in 10.0?  I'm looking mostly for stuff that's not easy to notice and which potentially impacts compatibility.

Comment: Pattern matching with associations from 10.3.1 to 10.4 (compare section Scope of respective ref pages).

Comment: @Xavier Hm, could that have anything to do with [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124603/12)?

Comment: Most operator forms added in the version 10 cycle were for functions that already existed prior to 10. But no, I do not recall the specifics.

Comment: Quantities can be specified in several `*Distribution` symbols (depending on the `UnitDimensions` of the quantity, this can change the distribution to a `QuantityDistribution`).